# Нужно ли тире?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужно ли тире в пословице "Человек человеку (—) волк"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Рассмотрим эту крылатую фразу как предложение, в котором подлежащее и сказуемое выражено существительными в И.п., но есть один пункт правил. Не помню, как он называется, но смысл в том, что тире не ставится, если есть какое-то дополнение между подл. и сказ., с уроков русского языка запомнил один пример: "Папа дяде брат". В этой пословице точно такая же ситуация, следовательно, тире не ставится.

Answer (score 1):

Если между подлежащим и сказуемым-существительным стоит вводное слово, обстоятельство или дополнение, а также союз или частица, то тире не ставится: Грач, конечно, птица умная и самостоятельная, но голоса у него нет (Пауст.); Мой отец для меня друг и наставник; Москва теперь порт пяти морей; Мой брат тоже инженер; Этот ручей лишь начало реки.(По ПАС Лопатина)
В Вашем примере между главными членами стоит дополнение, значит, тире не ставится. Валентин прав.